# How can I use a oauth2 token to create a connection with HTTParty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth-2.0, httparty, basecamp

I am trying to connect to the Basecamp API using HTTParty, I am however getting an issue with authentication.

I am getting an error `"HTTP Basic: Access denied"`, which doesn't make sense when I am trying to do OAuth.

The class looks a bit like this (The XXXX comes from other places, but is just hardcoded for the example here).

```
 class Basecamp
    include HTTParty

    def initialize(oauth_token)
        self.class.base_uri "https://basecamp.com/XXXXX/api/v1/"
        @options = {
            headers: {
                "Authorization" => oauth_token,
                "User-Agent" => 'XXXX (XXXXXX)'
            }
        }
    end

    def projects
        self.class.get('/projects.json', @options)
    end

    def users
        self.class.get('/people.json', @options)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation, the header should be

```
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_OAUTH_TOKEN
```

in your case, assuming `oauth_token` is the token, you are passing

```
Authorization: YOUR_OAUTH_TOKEN
```

Change the header to

```
"Authorization" => "Bearer #{oauth_token}",
```